# Can I use SATA SSD on my Lenovo V15 IGL?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Can I use SATA SSD on my Lenovo V15 IGL? Manual only mentions 2.5" SATA HDD. There's already a M2.2280 in there. Running Windows 10.

Comment: A SATA 2.5" mechanical HDD and a 2.5" SSD is the exact same form factor.  "M2.2280" does not tell us anything.  Please clarify the specifications of the device.  "M2.2280" can be SATA or NVMe. A M.2 SATA SSD would be incompatible with a M.2 NVMe connector.  **A mechanical 2.5" SATA HDD and 2.5" SATA SSD use the same connector.**

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to see whether it is recognized by the system and functions OK? You should be able to do this with minimal risk.

Answer (score -2):

I would open up the laptop and check. A quick search on internet and Youtube videos reveal it is different between G1 and G2 versions, but they both have 2 drive slots, one M2 and one SATA 2.5". But the problem seems to be that there might not be SATA connector included in cheaper versions of the laptop or versions of the laptop which came without SATA. So you may have to buy such extra connector also to be able to use it. The 2.5" SATA slot is left/next to the battery in both versions. Another option is to buy a larger M2.2280 (or M2.2242) drive instead.

https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Lenovo/Lenovo_V15_IGL/Lenovo_V15_IGL_Spec.PDF